# Need help exporting output of script to csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I [found a script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx) to give me the size of each subfolder within a directory.

The problem is I don't know where to put the `export-csv` command to get that output in a CSV.

As a bonus I would also like to throw in a `lastmodified` property to those subfolders if possible. But I realize that may require a different script entirely.

Here is the script:

```psh
$startFolder = "C:\Scripts"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
{
    $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
    $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
}
```

I've tried adding `| export-csv c:\path` to the very end, both inside and outside the bracket. I also tried adding it after the script command, ie `c:\script.ps1 | export-csv`. Each time I get the error that "An empty pipe element is not allowed."

Comment: please add the script to your question. and if you have another question, plese post another question.

Comment: There's lots of scripts and snippets on that page, which one are you referring to? Please post the code here.

Comment: Thanks for editing your post. You have a couple of issues. One is that the foreach contruct does not have output that is piped like most output is. Also your output now is not structured for CSV. Do you expect it to look the same as it does on screen?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process the output of a `foreach` loop with a pipeline you must either collect its output in a variable:

```psh
$results = foreach ($i in $colItems) {
  ...
}
$results | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType
```

or run it in an expression (i.e. in parentheses):

```psh
(foreach ($i in $colItems) {
  ...
}) | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType
```

However, personally I'd prefer [`ForEach-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx) over `foreach` loops (for differences between the two see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object.aspx)), because the former does work with pipelines:

```psh
Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse |
  Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} |
  Sort-Object |
  ForEach-Object {
    ...
  } |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType
```

With that said, you may not want a loop in the first place. The [`Export-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) cmdlet processes a list of objects and writes the properties of the input objects as fields to a CSV file. Since you already have object input you could simply select the properties you want to export:

```psh
Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse |
  Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} |
  Sort-Object |̣
  Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType
```

Custom properties can be added for instance as [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```psh
Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse |
  Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} |
  Sort-Object |̣
  Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, @{n='FolderSize';e={
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName |
      Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum |
      Select-Object -Expand Sum
  }} |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This script worked best: "Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse |
  Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} |
  Sort-Object |̣
  Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, @{n='FolderSize';e={
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName |
      Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum |
      Select-Object -Expand Sum
  }} |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType." But the problem is it wasn't giving info on each subdirectory. The original script wasn't either, as I discovered when I looked closer. Possibly because they were mapped Sharepoint drives? Either way I'm using TreeSize now

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` doesn't include grandchilds. You need to add the parameter `-Recurse`. Probably a better option for folder size calculation is using the `FileSystemObject` COM object: `$fso = New-Object -COM 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'; $fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).Size`